# Why the same color in fragment and activity looks different?

Tags: android, android-layout, colors

I use color `#7700ff00` on `Activity` and the same on some `Fragment`s which lay this `Activity`. But they looks different:

[image]

Why this happens and how fix this?

Comment: We need more context here. Can you please add your xml file of the fragment and the fragment itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, because in case of `Fragment` you have `#7700ff00` over `#7700ff00`. The last is the color of `Activity` layout's background. Use fully transparent background for the `Fragment` layout.